# When disolving a iron pill for titration, why do I use sulfuric acid instead of nitric or hydrochloric acid?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, analytical-chemistry, transition-metals, titration

In a titration to decide the iron content of a pill we dissolved the iron in sulfuric acid and then titrated it with cerium(IV) sulfate. But I just wondered what's wrong with using nitric and hydrochloric acid in this scenario?

Comment: Hint: Ceric sulfate is a strong oxidizing agent, and so is nitric acid. HCl can be oxidized. Can you think of interferences in redox titrations?

Comment: @ M. Farooq Not really sure what to look for. If i used nitric acid it would already oxidise my iron to Fe3+ ions i suppose?. And if i were to guess when using  HCL the Ceric sulfate would react with the CL- ions.? not really sure

Comment: Yes this sounds plausible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, cerium(IV) sulfate is a strong oxidising agent, hence, using $\ce{HCl}$ would likely be oxidised to form $\ce{Cl}$ of higher oxidation state. Therefore, the titre would be vastly higher than expected.

$\ce{HNO3},$ on the other hand, is an oxidising agent and would oxidise $\ce{Fe}$ to a higher oxidation state than expected (of $\ce{Fe^3+}$). Hence, not as much cerium(IV) sulfate would be needed to reach the endpoint, resulting in a titre lower than expected.

Therefore, $\ce{SO4^2-}$, being a relatively unreactive species, is the best reactant in this case.